# How to read data from external fingerprint scanner in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, android-fingerprint-api, time-and-attendance, digital-persona-sdk

I want to save multiple user fingerprints in Firebase database. So, If a user logins in my android app, he'll scan the finger from the external fingerprint scanner connected to my android device. After scanning I should get some kind of data back, I'll check if that data exists in my firebase, I'll login the user.

So that's it.

Can anyone help me with that?

I'm using the external fingerprint named: DigitalPersona U.are.U 4500 scanner

[image: Finger print image]

I think Native android has API's for reading the data from external fingerprint. But, I want to implement the same in flutter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.